# Creating a Serial Number based upon values in a table

Tags: vba

I am having difficulty coming up with this code. I know enough vba to get myself in trouble. What I am trying to do is to generate serial numbers for shelf locations. I want it to be able to auto generate the numbers based upon certain parameters and rules. So in a warehouse there are certain  rows, shelves, and positions. If I was to put in a table the number of each of them e.g.

3 Rows
2 Shelves
4 Positions

I would want it to spit out the relevant serial numbers based upon how many rows/shelves/positions there are. In this case it would be:

R01-S01-P01,
R01-S01-P02,
R01-S01-P03,
R01-S01-P04,
R01-S02-P01,
R01-S02-P02,
R01-S02-P03,
R01-S02-P04,
R02-S01-P01,
R02-S01-P02,
R02-S01-P03,
R01-S01-P04,
R01-S02-P01,
etc...

Any thoughts or help you can give would be greatly appreciated!

```
Dim i As Integer, iPos As Integer, c As Integer, iRow As Integer, d As Integer, iShl As Integer

iPos = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "J").Value
iShl = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "I").Value
iRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "H").Value
For i = 1 To iPos * iShl * iRow
 Cells(i, 3).Value = i
    For d = 1 To iShl
        Cells(i, 2).Value = d
            For c = 1 To iRow
                Cells(c, 1).Value = i
            Next c
    Next d
Next i
```

Comment: Possibly something using a 3-dimensional array?

Comment: Can you post what code you have so far? As a hint, you're looking to nest 3 loops to create each portion of your Serial number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3749080. Good attempt. Here is my code below. I've test, and it seems to work with how I'm understanding what you are looking for.

The biggest change I made, was to pull the bit out that creates the 2 digit number (for those numbers less than 10) out into a separate function.

**UPDATE**

I've changed the code to create a check for blank or 0 and still create serial numbers with that criteria.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateSerials()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i_P     As Integer
    Dim iPos    As Integer
    Dim initP   As Integer
    Dim i_R     As Integer
    Dim iRow    As Integer
    Dim initR   As Integer
    Dim i_S     As Integer
    Dim iShl    As Integer
    Dim initS   As Integer

    iPos = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "J").Value
    iShl = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "I").Value
    iRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "H").Value

    If iPos = 0 Then
        initP = 0
    Else
        initP = 1
    End If

    If iShl = 0 Then
        initS = 0
    Else
        initS = 1
    End If

    If iRow = 0 Then
        initR = 0
    Else
        initR = 1
    End If

    Range("C:C").ClearContents
    For i_R = initR To iRow
        For i_S = initS To iShl
            For i_P = initP To iPos
                Range("C1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
                    "R" & DoubleDigit(i_R) & "-S" & DoubleDigit(i_S) & "-P" & DoubleDigit(i_P)
            Next i_P
        Next i_S
    Next i_R

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C:C")) & " serial numbers were created"
End Sub

Function DoubleDigit(i_Input As Integer) As String
    If i_Input < 10 Then
        DoubleDigit = "0" & i_Input
    Else
        DoubleDigit = i_Input
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I have one more question. How would I update this to still work if one of the values for the cells that iPos, iShl, and iRow use was null or zero. If I leave those blank it stops the loop from going forward. I would like for it to just put a "00" value in the serial number if that was the case.

Comment: I guess I would ask if you have shelves, rows, or positions that are labeled `00`, or are you looking for a way to pop up a box to say you can't enter 0 or blank?

Comment: It would be the first one. If there is no shelf, row, or position it would be 00 for that one

Comment: It would be the first one. If there is no shelf, row, or position it would be 00 for that one

Comment: I think I have an idea, but want to clarify 1 more thing. Let's say you put 2 in the row field. The row positions you would use would be `00` and `01`. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: No... If you had a 2 in the field it would start at 01, 02. If for what ever reason the bar code did not have a shelf or row or position, it would be be a 00 value like R01-S00-P01, R01-S00-P02, R01-S00-P03, R02-S00-P01, R02-S00-P02, R02-S00-P03, etc...